# Websocket gets closed after sending out string : Play framework 2.1.x

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am using Play framework 2.1.x

I could successfully create a websocket but it quickly closes on sending the data to client.
There seems to be a mechanism in 1.x by using await function - but its deprecated I understand as the WebSocketController is now deprecated.
How do I ensure the "life" of my websocket

```
public static WebSocket<String> loggedInSocket() {

    try {
        final Http.Session session = session();
        String username = session(AppConstants.USERNAME);
        connection = getConnection(username);
        connection = XMPPConnectionHandler.performLogin(xmppLogin.getLoggedinuser().getUsername(),xmppLogin.getLoggedinuser().getPassword(),connection);
        getAllData();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return new WebSocket<String>() {
        public void onReady(WebSocket.In<String> in, WebSocket.Out<String> out) {
            System.out.println("ready");
            in.onMessage(new F.Callback() {
                public void invoke(String event) {
                    System.out.println(event);
                }

                @Override
                public void invoke(Object a) throws Throwable {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

            in.onClose(new F.Callback0() {
                public void invoke() {
                    System.out.println("Disconnected");
                }
            });
            out.write("Hello");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was due to an exception encountered that the socket was closing.